# Lifting map and joint probability

Tags: quantum-state, density-matrix

How to use *lifting map* approach to calculate the following joint probability after equation (12) of [Quantum-like model of diauxie in Escherichia coli: Operational description of precultivation effect](https://sci-hub.ee/https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0022519312004444) ?

[image: lifting_map]